# get random integers from range of integers

Tags: python, random, while-loop, integer

I need to make a list of unique random integers from a range (start, stop) with a specific number of integers (number_of_ints).
So basically a function `get_unique_random_integers(1, 100, 10)` should return a list with 10 integers, e.g. [93, 23, 6, 26, 90, 29, 59, 12, 15, 86]. It's also required to use the while loop and randint function.

So far I wrote this but the function is returning None.

```
import random
def get_unique_random_integers(start, stop, number_of_ints):
    random_list = []
    while int(start) < int(stop):
        res = random.randint(start, stop)
        if res not in random_list:
            start += 1
    return random_list.append(res*number_of_ints)
print(get_unique_random_integers(1, 100, 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `while` is check for `number_of_ints` and decreasing it with 1.
Just append result to list `random_list.append(res)`.

```
import random
def get_unique_random_integers(start, stop, number_of_ints):
    random_list = []
    while number_of_ints:
        res = random.randint(start, stop)
        if res not in random_list:
            random_list.append(res)
        number_of_ints -= 1
    return random_list
print(get_unique_random_integers(1, 9, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.sample` here as `random.sample` selects given number of selection from the given sample without replacement.

Example :-

```
import random

start = 5
end = 10
number_of_ints = 3

print(random.sample(range(start, end + 1), number_of_ints))
# prints [5, 9, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

`return random_list.append(res*number_of_ints)`.

The `.append()` is an in-place function which returns `None` i.e returns nothing. So it becomes `return None`.

You should add the element to the list first then return it:

```
random_list.append(res*number_of_ints)
return random_list
```

Also, `return` marks the end of a function. So, only one element would be returned. You should move `return return random_list` outside the loop.

```
import random
def get_unique_random_integers(start, stop, number_of_ints):
    random_list = []
    start1=0
    while start1 < int(number_of_ints):
        res = random.randint(start, stop)
        if res not in random_list:
            start1 += 1
            random_list.append(res*number_of_ints)
    return random_list
print(get_unique_random_integers(1, 100, 10))
```